# What is the Taylor series for the function $f(x)=\cos(x)$ centered at $a=(-\pi/4$)?

Tags: taylor-expansion

The title is the extent of the problem. It is a problem from my Calculus II practice test that I am having trouble solving.

Comment: Well, what does your Calculus II book say about the Taylor series of a $C^\infty$ function centered at $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

First you need your derivatives.

$f (x) = \cos x$

$f ' (x) = -\sin x$

$f '' (x) = -\cos x $

$f ''' (x) = \sin x $

$f '''' (x) = \cos x $

Now you need to substitute in $a = \frac{π}{4}$ into all those above.

$f (π/4) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} $

$f ' (π/4) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt2} $

$f '' (π/4) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt2} $

$f ''' (π/4) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} $

$f '''' (π/4) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} $

Finally put it all in the Taylor series:

$\cos(x) = f (a)\frac{(x-a)^0}{0!} + f ' (a)\frac{(x-a)^1}{1!} + f '' (a)\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!} + f ''' (a)\frac{(x-a)^3}{3!} + f '''' (a)\frac{(x-a)^4}{4!} + ... $

$\therefore \cos(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(x-π/4) - \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\frac{(x-π/4)^2}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\frac{(x-π/4)^3}{6} + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\frac{(x-π/4)^4}{24} + ...$

Comment: @AndrewM: Do you understand